# Why does my compiler complain about a missing template argument for a concept?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Initially  I had following concept which worked just fine:

```
template<typename T,  typename...KEYS>
concept js_concept = requires(T t, int index, std::string& json_body, KEYS... keys, std::string key) {
    { t.template get_value<T>(keys) } -> std::same_as<T>;
    { t.template get_value<T>(key) } -> std::same_as<T>;
};
```

The two above is just to have a distinction between 1/several args.

Now I would simply implement this by:

```
class JsoncppImpl {

  template<typename T, typename... KEYS>
  T get_value(KEYS&& ... keys) {
    /// impl
  } 
  template<typename T>
  T get_value(std::string key) {
    /// impl
  } 
}
```

And the use case:

```
class JsonUtil {
public:
    template<js_concept JSON_OPERATOR>
    JsonUtil(std::string body, JSON_OPERATOR&& json_impl){
        m_st = json_impl.get_value<std::string>(body);

    }
  std::string m_st;
};

int main( ){
    std::string body = "c++";
    JsonUtil<JsoncppImpl::value> jsoncpp(body, JsoncppImpl{});
    return 0;
}
```

That works just fine. If I do the following addition by adding another function to the concept returning a template argument:

```
 template<typename T , typename VALUE, typename...KEYS>
concept js_concept = requires(T t, int index, std::string& json_body, KEYS... keys, std::string key) { //
    // setting consts  here is  pointless (these are  treated as  pr values)
    { t.template get_value<T>(keys) } -> std::same_as<T>;
    { t.template get_value<T>(key) } -> std::same_as<T>;
    { t.template release() } -> std::same_as<VALUE>;

};
```

and adding the additional function to the implemention:

```
JsoncppImpl::release(){ return std::move(m_some_internal_value);}
```

The variable ´m_some_internal_value´ is just some type well defined within JsoncppImpl. It can even be defined as a primitive type.

Now using the release function:

```
     template<js_concept JSON_OPERATOR>
    JsonUtil::JsonUtil(std::string body, JSON_OPERATOR&& json_impl){
        m_st = json_impl.get_value<std::string>(body);
        auto val = json_impl.release();

    }
```

Gives following compiler error:

```
js_concept' requires more than 1 template argument; provide the remaining arguments explicitly to use it here
    template<js_concept JSON_OPERATOR>
```

Comment: "*the compiler dont know which of the three template argument should be binded the the one provided*" What is the error message?

Comment: Okay so by shifting around the template argument it works. However, I still would like to know why the compiler is for that specific template argument , it suddently wants the template argument explicitly while it did not ask for such before

Comment: You say "the template argument" as though your new concept only took *one*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cpp
template<js_concept JSON_OPERATOR>
JsonUtil(std::string body, JSON_OPERATOR&& json_impl) {}
```

Is equivalent to

```cpp
template<typename JSON_OPERATOR>
JsonUtil(std::string body, JSON_OPERATOR&& json_impl)
requires js_concept<JSON_OPERATOR> {}
```

`KEYS...` empty, so it works fine. (But I really doubt if it behaves as you expect...

When you add another template parameter, you have to explicitly provide it since the compiler has no idea where it comes from.

You could do like this,

```cpp
template<typename VALUE, js_concept<VALUE> JSON_OPERATOR>
JsonUtil::JsonUtil(std::string body, JSON_OPERATOR&& json_impl){
```

Comment: But how does it know that the VALUE should be bind to "VALUE" placeholder of the concept and not for example, T or KEYS?

Comment: @A2LBK. *In a type-constraint, a concept takes one less template argument than its parameter list demands, because the contextually deduced type is implicitly used as the first argument of the concept.* from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Concepts

Comment: The first parameter is reserved for `JSON_OPERATOR`, and fill in the rest parameters in order
So `js_concept<VALUE> JSON_OPERATOR` will be `js_concept<JSON_OPERATOR, VALUE>` `KEYS` also empty here.

Comment: So my concept has the following template signature:

`template <typename T, typename VALUE, typename... KEYS> `. Are you saying the compiler will regardless of the how I choose to order the above signature (i.e. even when changing e.g. switching T with VALUE, the compiler will still be able to deduce it correctly

Comment: No, they won't. The only thing matters here is **the first parameter** is reserved/used.

Comment: You can see it as passing template arguments from the second parameter.